# Cannot read line by line in Python ! (for line in fh: io.UnsupportedOperation: read)

Tags: python, file

Hi I'm doing a client/server program that can read files.

When i click on certain files, it should read the text line by line.
But it shows the following error instead:

```
line 65, in mouseHover
    for line in fh:
io.UnsupportedOperation: read
```

My code:

```
def mouseHover(event):
    x = lbox.curselection()[0]
    file = lbox.get(x)
    self.s.send(("fdown~" + file).encode("utf-8")) #must have
    self.s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")#must ahve
    self.s.send("OK".encode("utf-8"))
    fh = open(file, 'wb') #must have
    for line in fh:
        self.s.recv(1024) #must have
    sys.stdout.flush()
    self.text.delete('1.0', tk.END)
    self.text.insert(tk.END, line)
lbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", mouseHover)
```

[Image of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypBMr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use another mode, e.g. "wb+" (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

```
fh = open(file, 'w+')
```

Comment: no more error, but i cant read any text from the files.

Comment: are you sure that you need binary data instead of strings?

Comment: String will do, so this is why my text is not showing ?

Comment: do you know about this error ? "AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'readlines'"

Comment: @ZhuangAh if `w+` doesn't work for you, then I don't have other ideas for now...